# Panel Ground Wire Routing

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

The space between the right side of the panel box and the grounding bar is only 1/2" making getting the wires in and out a bit tight. But running it in between the neutral And ground bars there is not a straight pass and it runs against the ground lig and the neutral plastic protector.

And running the ground wire to the left and counter clockwise will clutter up the left side and waste a lot more wire.

Which is the lesser of the evils? Thinking running it to the far right gives a clean pathway
and doesn't risk making contact with the neutral bar would be best. Assuming this is all preference and nothing code related driving this?

[image: Rubs]

[image: close up]

[image: full panel]

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use a pair of pliers to **actually bend** the end of the wire neatly into a 90 degree bend that doesn't take a trip around Robin Hood's Barn to get there.

That would, I suppose, fall under "in a workmanlike manner" for code purposes. Being updated to "professional and skillful manner" in 2023 code. Article 110.12 "Mechanical Execution of Work"

In which case there's plenty of room on either side, or both sides.

Comment: First you can't say "master"/"slave" in computer terminology. Now you can't say "workman like" in NEC...

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Before you know it, "manner" will be out of style.

Comment: Ok, I know how to do that of course but was worried about too sharp of bends.

Comment: Depends on thickness. For 12 AWG and 14 AWG really not an issue. With larger wires you need to be a little more careful, but even then, consider that it is perfectly OK, in fact *required* on standard screw terminals (e.g., receptacles) to bend around a screw. So consider that as a definitely permissible minimum turn radius.